# Installing Phusion Passenger with Ruby 2.1.0

Tags: phusion-passenger, ruby

I'm following [the guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu) for installing Passenger on Ubuntu, but when running

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

it tries to install Ruby 1.9.1. I already have Ruby 2.1.0 (installed via RVM). How can I make Passenger use the existing Ruby instead of installing the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your rvm default set to 2.1?  (e.g. `rvm use --default 2.1.0` )

Try installing passenger gem (which comes with an apache & nginx installer)

`gem install passenger`

`passenger-install-apache2-module`

once it is done installing it should also give you a few lines to paste into your apache config. Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-passenger